# running a firefox profile in selenium python doesnt work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

This is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

print("Openning Browser")
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("C:/Users/myname/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/qljcimja.whatsapp_riddle_bot")
fo = Options()
fo.add_argument("-profile")
fo.add_argument("C:/Users/myname/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/qljcimja.whatsapp_riddle_bot")
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
main_win = webdriver.Firefox(fp, executable_path='C:/Drivers/geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64/geckodriver.exe', capabilities=firefox_capabilities, firefox_options=fo)
print("Done Openning Browser\nStarting Website")
main_win.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
...
```

There is a lot more code into this but i am really sure the error is from the above block of code. So when i run my code it prints `Openning Browser` as usual in the terminal but after the window opens it still doesnt open the url after some waiting like around 30 secs it pops an error as below

```
(.venv) PS E:\Nayan,s file\PythonProjects\whatsapp riddle bot> python launcher.py
Openning Browser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Nayan,s file\PythonProjects\whatsapp riddle bot\launcher.py", line 3, in <module>
    main.main()
  File "E:\Nayan,s file\PythonProjects\whatsapp riddle bot\main.py", line 75, in main
    main_win = webdriver.Firefox(fp, executable_path='C:/Drivers/geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64/geckodriver.exe', capabilities=firefox_capabilities, firefox_options=fo)
  File "E:\Nayan,s file\PythonProjects\whatsapp riddle bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__        
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "E:\Nayan,s file\PythonProjects\whatsapp riddle bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "E:\Nayan,s file\PythonProjects\whatsapp riddle bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session    
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "E:\Nayan,s file\PythonProjects\whatsapp riddle bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "E:\Nayan,s file\PythonProjects\whatsapp riddle bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061)
```

Yes its a riddle bot i made for my friends and ignore all the folder names

so i was curios and removed `fo`, `fp` and `firefox_capabilities` variables and ran the driver with only the driver_path variable and it ran.

But i want the profile to be loaded cause i always have to take my phone to scan the code to get whatsapp web running, imagine while i am testing everytime i have to scan again and again.

In short i wanna know why this is happening(like is it a bug in selenium or anything) and is there way to workaround?

Comment: so basically you want to launch firefox profile with webdriver ? also can you mention browser version  ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Ya i do and firefox version is 90.0.2 and the driver version 0.29.1